# Django - Displaying alert messages in base template

Tags: html, css, django

I am displaying alert messages in my base template with a simple for loop. My issue is that when the message gets displayed it pushes down the div for whatever page is getting the alert. Obviously this is because for the alert I am creating a new div and inserting it at the top of the page but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this? I could solve this issue but just hard coding the message inside of the div into the specific pages where I want the message to be displayed but I would prefer leaving it in the base template if possible.

Is there some way with css that I could possibly make the div display on top of another div maybe? Or maybe simply just changing how my messages displayed will fix it? I have tried a few different solutions and fit for what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated!

base template:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    {% block extra_head %}
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    
    {% block css_files %} {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8f82ba5152.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% include 'includes/nav_bar.html' %}

{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" id="message">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}


{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% include 'includes/footer.html' %}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
var message_ele = document.getElementById("message");

setTimeout(function(){ 
   message_ele.style.display = "none"; 
}, 3000);


</script>
{% block extra_scripts %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

adding a picture for a clearer description of my issue
[image]

as you can see the alert message literally pushes my next highest div downwards and white space is created between the two

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what it is exactly that you want to achieve. Could you please elaborate more on what you want to achieve and/or what the issue is exactly?

Comment: Yes sorry for my bad explanation haha, I attached a picture to better explain what I mean. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your base template should provide defaults for most or all pages, but make it possible to override the default in cases where it's less than ideal.

Here, put the base template message code into a named block.

```
{% block default_messages %}
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" id="message">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock default_messages %}
```

Now in any page where you find that the default is undesirable, you can override it. In `page_template.html`:

```
{% block default_messages %}
    <!-- delete the default, i.e. omit { { block.super } } -->
{% endblock default_messages %}
```

and handle `messages` explicitly, elsewhere in `page_template.html`, perhaps with a `%include` if the block of message code is going to be useful in multiple pages.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

put these inside div tag